# Can an earth-like planet exist in a circumbinary orbit around two k-class stars?While also having up to two dozen other planets in circumbinary orbit?

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, astronomy, stars

I have a plot arc in mind, but it all hinges on the feasibility of an earth-like world existing in circumbinary orbit around two k-class (or g-class) stars. The looming danger in the story arc is that the stars (already in close orbit to each other) grow closer over millions of years, and are due to collide, which is to be a world-ending event.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It hinges on the feasibility? Who's your target audience? Astronomy PhDs? It's not my intention to sound rude (I probably do), but hinging on the feasibility of something you don't, yourself, understand suggests that it actually doesn't hinge on it at all. Please remember per the [help/on-topic], we're here to help you build *imaginary worlds.* While we deal with a lot of Real World questions, you should have an actual worldbuilding reason for asking them. I strongly urge you to read through the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The planet's orbital radius will need to be at least 2-4 times that of its suns, and its year will have to take at least 3-8 times the period of the two suns. Your suns will be between .45-1.04 solar masses each, and if you assume that the suns are similar to Earth's, the orbital radius should be 1.41 AU to get a similar amount of radiation as Earth, and the suns cannot orbit each other at a distance more than .35 AU. There should be enough space for all of those planets to exist.